# nested data in ul does not display

Tags: knockout.js

I got the following nested list but does not display in the list.

html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:parents">
    <li data-bind="text:name">
        <ul data-bind="foreach:kids">
            <li data-bind="text:name"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

script

```
vm = function () {
    this.parents = [{
        name: "Piet",
        kids: [{
            name: "ted"
        }, {
            name: "fred"
        }]
    }, {
        name: "Ed",
        kids: [{
            name: "hoer"
        }, {
            name: "kut"
        }]
    }]
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/2LWFh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: parents ">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: kids">
           <li data-bind="text: name">
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2LWFh/5/